# How do you match a regex to a google search correction string in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I need to use regex to get the "Did you mean? portion of the source code from a google search. I am not aware of any difference between the regex in C# and in javascript, but

This is the regex I have in C#:

```
output = output.Replace("\"", "");
string regex = "Did you mean: </span><a href=/search.[a-zA-Z0-9=&;_-]{1,}q=[a-zA-Z0-9+-]{1,}";
```

This is what i have in javascript:

```
var response = this.responseText.replace("\"", "")
var regex = new RegExp("Did you mean: </span><a href=.search.[a-zA-Z0-9=&;_-]{1,}q=[a-zA-Z0-9+-]{1,}")
```

This is part of the response I am getting back from google:

```
style="color:#cc0000">Did you mean: </span><a href=/search?hl=en&amp;safe=off&amp;&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=DXtLTd2hKYjKgQfJ0sBD&amp;ved=0CBIQBSgA&amp;q=Linkin+Park-In+The+End&amp;spell=1"class=spell>Linkin Park-In <b><i>The</i></b> End</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></div><!--a--><h2 class=hd>Search Results</h2><div id=ires><ol><li class="g videobox" id=videobox><h3 class=r><a href="/search?q=Linkin+Park-In+Th+End&amp;hl=en&amp;
```

How can I make the javascript regex match correctly?

NOTE: I already know that the C# regex only matches once on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use regex here?

If you notice the source code, the Did you Mean section is inside a Div which has ID `topstuff`. So you can get the `innerHtml` of this Div.

Comment: how do you do that in JavaScript? Sorry, I am a C# programmer

Comment: document.getElementById('topstuff').innerHTML would grab it for you, with some additional HTML in there to clean out. If you are using something like jQuery, you could do a $('#topstuff').html().